# Preserve painted client area between calls to WM_PAINT in win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to paint(draw) text on the client area on a window in response to some event(not in the `WM_PAINT` message), so how can I preserve the state of the client area between calls to `WM_PAINT`? I understand that every time there is a `WM_PAINT` message(or window refreshes) the window gets redrawn and everything out side `WM_PAINT` doesn't matter anymore. I think I will be able to communicate better with code, so here is what I have now.

```
HDC mdc;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
                    LPSTR lpszArgument, int nFunsterStil)
{   
    LoadBitmap(...); // for skinning the app.
    stuff.. 
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     case WM_PAINT:
         PAINTSTRUCT ps;

             HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
             BITMAP bm;

             HDC dcSkin = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
             GetObject(hSkinBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);
             SelectObject(dcSkin, hSkinBmp);

             BitBlt(dcSkin, 0, 0, wWidth, wHeight, mdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
             BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, wWidth, wHeight, dcSkin, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

             DeleteDC(dcSkin);

             EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
     break;


     case WM_LBUTTONDOWN;

          HDC hdc = GetDC( hwnd );

          mdc = CreateCompatibleDC( hdc );


          LPRECT rect;
          GetClientRect( hwnd, rect);

          SelectObject( mdc, CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, rect->right, rect->bottom ) );

          BitBlt( mdc,0,0,rect->right,rect->bottom,hdc,0,0,SRCCOPY );


          HFONT hfont = CreateFont( 0, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                          DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, 
                          PROOF_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS   , 0 );

          HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject( mdc, hfont );

          SetTextColor( mdc, RGB(255,0,0) );
          SetBkColor( mdc, RGB(255,255,0) );
          TextOut( mdc, 50, 150, logintext.c_str(), strlen( logintext.c_str() ) );

          SelectObject( mdc, hOldFont );
          ReleaseDC( hwnd, hdc);
          InvalidateRect( hwnd, 0, TRUE );

     break;
}
```

As you can see, I have to paint the client area of the window with a bmp, then when mouse button down message comes, I have to output some text on top of the skinned client area.
What I am doing is saving the memory dc created in the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message and trying to paint the window dc first with the dc for skin then the dc for text(memory dc created in `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`).

The skin bitmap show as it is supposed to, but the Text doesn't.

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: What you need to do is tell your `WM_PAINT` handler, "Hey, when you paint, could you also draw the login text? Thanks."

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to draw things outside of WM_PAINT and have them persist. Unfortunatly that's not how windows works.

You need to be able to redraw *everything* in your WM_PAINT handler as the contents of the window can be destroyed at any moment and redrawn, so you have to structure your program to be able to do this. Instead of drawing anything outside of the WM_PAINT hander instead set some flags or other state telling the program what should be on the screen and then invalidate the area of the screen so that a WM_PAINT will be issued to draw that area.

One alternative which might be easier for you is to draw everything to an offscreen bitmap whenever it needs updating, and have the WM_PAINT function just draw that bitmap on the screen so it's always up to date.

Comment: I understand that I have to redraw everything in WM_PAINT, that's why I saved "mdc", but I think I was wrong, I need to save a memory bitmap ? I have edited the code, please have a look. I thought about setting flags but unfortunately there are so many variables to consider when drawing text, so I dropped that idea. Help me correct the code.

Comment: Ok re-reading your post I think you did know all that and my reply isn't worth the upvotes. I don't want to delete it as it might be useful to someone but how can I disclaim any credit for it?

AS for the code, I'll try to have a look later what is going wrong as you do seem to be trying to do what I suggested, no time now. I hope someone else can step in :)